# AzureDevOps: Grant read-only acces to all repos in organization

Tags: azure-devops

We need to grant "Read" access to all git repos in our AzureDevOps organization. I don't think there is a common root to all team projets GIT repos (like it's the case for TFVC). Each team projet seems to be "it's own git server".

Currently, only a few collection-leve groups are automatically added to new projects. "Project Collection Build Service Account" would grant just enough access to repos but would grant permissions in other modules.

Is there a way to edit the process template as we did in TFS? I could then create a collection-level group and ensure access to GIT Repos root level.

Unless I'm just missing out on some obvious alternative solution.

Comment: PS: We already granted acces to the group to all "Readers" Team-Project-level groups. We just need to make sure it's added to new projetcts as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For general DevOps organization, you can't edit the process template as you did in TFS.

I suggest that you could create a new group in collection level, then add it to team projects manually.

Comment: This is already done. What I'm looking for is a way to make sure this group will automatically be added to new projects.

Comment: @JustinMasséj It is not supported for general DevOps organization. If the organization is migrated from DevOps server/tfs, you can custom process template.